# Вывод постов на страницу по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Имеем следующую форму с выбором даты:

```
<form method="post" name="delivery_date" action="date.php">
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="" id="example-date-input"> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-3">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Имеем обработку этой формы в date.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // Включаем вывод всех ошибок
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['delivery_date']))
{
    $form_date = $_POST['delivery_date'];
    printf($form_date);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery_date='$form_date' AND delivery=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);


    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s\n", $res["phone"]);
        printf ("%s\n", $res["name"]);
        printf ("%s\n", $res["surname"]);
        printf ("%s\n", $res["second_name"]);
        printf ("%s\n", $res["comment"]);

    }
}
?>
```

По результату выполнения которой получаем строку со значениями типа:
2019-01-01 +79991234567 Имя Фамилия Отчество Комментарий.

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне вывести эти полученные данные на исходной странице?

Answer (score 0):

1 Можете использовать сессию (очень примерный пример):

```
// at the very top of your form file (let's say it's form_file.html) and date.php file
<?php session_start(); ?> // closing tag is only for .html file 
// in date.php
if (isset($_POST['delivery_date'])) {
    ...
     while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $res["phone"];
        ...
        // when it's all set and done
        header('Location: {path/}form_file.html'); // {path/} is when both your files doesn't stored in root directory or it has different paths

// in form_file.html somewhere you want to retrieve data
<?php foreach ($_SESSION as $item) { ?>
    echo $item['phone'];
    ...
```

2 Можете использовать jQuery ajax. Не буду описывать, т.к. вопрос касается php реализации.
З.Ы. Всё это есть в интернетах в более чем достаточном количестве и понятном изложении. Гуглите, и Да нагуглится!